# How to build for ios on Windows (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, react-native

Is there any opportunity to build react-native project for ios on Windows? Is there any service for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Not possible for iOS as of now (If you are not going to use [MAC on VMware](http://www.sysprobs.com/mac-windows-featured-post)). 
However you can use for Android & read More details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html#content).

**NOTE: This guide focuses on Android development. You'll need a Mac to build iOS apps.**

> As React Native on iOS requires a Mac and most of the engineers at
>   Facebook and contributors use Macs, support for OS X is a top
>   priority. However, we would like to support developers using Linux and
>   Windows too. We believe we'll get the best Linux and Windows support
>   from people using these operating systems on a daily basis.
>
> Therefore, Linux and Windows support for the development environment
>   is an ongoing community responsibility. This can mean filing issues
>   and submitting PRs, and we'll help review and merge them. We are
>   looking forward to your contributions and appreciate your patience.
>
> As of version 0.14 Android development with React native is mostly
>   possible on Linux and Windows. You'll need to install Node.js 4.0 or
>   newer. On Linux we recommend installing watchman, otherwise you might
>   hit a node file watching bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud build service, such as Circle CI or Mobile Center, to build iOS react-native applications and even automatically run Appium tests. The feedback cycle would be much longer than on your local machine, though.

Some folks choose to break the Apple EULA and run MacOS in a VirtualBox as a kind of "hackintosh" virtual machine on their Windows PCs. This supposedly works very well, and runs at near-native build speeds.